# Finding the environment variables in assembler

Tags: assembly, gdb, environment-variables

I'm trying to exploit a buffer overflow for an assignment, and I have to access the environment variables (read one of them), but I have no clue where to look for them. I'm using gdb to inspect memory, but I just can't find the environment variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a global variable (`char **environ`) which should exist in the running executable's symbol table, if that was compiled with the `-g` option.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you have found since time.
Environment varialbes are stocked on the esp register, by example on my current exercice, I can show the environment variables with this command (starti is for break at the first instruction):

```sh
(gdb) starti
(gdb) x/50s $esp+450
```

Comment: The start of the env vars on the stack is right above the command line args.  So at process startup, `pop ecx` (load `argc`) / `lea edx, [esp + ecx*4 + 4]` to get a pointer to the first entry of the env array.  (One past the NULL pointer that terminates `argv[]`).  This is of course assuming the i386 System V ABI, e.g. for Linux.  Other OSes might have things in different places at process-startup.  (But may still pass `main` a 3rd arg, `char *envp[]`)